# Source code all greyed out

Tags: netbeans-8

I copied my project from one local pc to another local pc (no network involved).
I did this using export to zip and import. I can open project on the target pc, and I can open each source program (there are 4), but the source code on all are greyed out and I cannot make changes, nor can I run file.

I read the questions that may already answer this problem, but none applied to me.

Files in question are JAVA Netbeans source code. Don't know how to determine if they were flagged as read only on the target PC. Did not have this problem on the source PC.

I have been working on this all day.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: In which application are you opening it in?

Comment: Are the files marked as read-only?